# How to configure vim to start automatically when my PC boots?

Tags: startup, vim

My version of vim has many plugins installed: ruby, php, python etc.

When I invoke `vim` from the terminal, I have to wait ~ 10 seconds before `vim` finishes starting.

Is it possible to have it load when Ubuntu starts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but I don't see using it without a terminal (unless you use gVim). You can add it to .bashrc in your home directory ( or .bash_profile under some circumstances ).

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddingProgramToSessionStartup for instructions on adding startup applications in Ubuntu. The command would be one of the following:

```
gvim #vim GUI version

gnome-terminal --command 'vim' #execute ONLY vim in a terminal

gnome-terminal #start a terminal, and vim will load if it's in .bashrc
```

Replace "gnome-terminal" and "--command" with your favored terminal emulator and syntax for running commands on startup, respectively.

Comment: In case you need to run other programs from the command line, you can use Ctrl+z to pause vim while you do something else, and the 'fg' command in bash to restore your previous editor state. Bash job control is awesome.

Comment: Oh! ctrl+z and "fg" - is awesome! =)

Comment: How can I use this to also make vim to open a specific file at startup? I tried `gnome-terminal --command 'nvim path/to/file.md'` but it opened an empty file with the same name. The command in the quotes works from the terminal but here something gets lost.

Comment: @nocibambi I'd guess that you're relying on a relative path rather than an absolute path. You'll either need to account for the working directory or switch to using an absolute path.

Comment: @Barbarrosa I solved it by "embedding" nvim parameters into the gnome-terminal command:  `gnome-terminal --command 'nvim  -c "e ~/path/to/file"'`